# GSAP import error: 'node_modules/@gsap/business/types/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, gsap

G'day SO!

I am getting a persistent error in my Vite + React + GSAP + TypeScript environment on attempted import in all tsx files that require it: 'node_modules/@gsap/business/types/index.d.ts' is not a module.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "files": [
    "./node_modules/@gsap/business/types/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Has been added to tsconfig.json & problem still continues.

Import is:

```
import { gsap } from '@gsap/business'
```

What am I overlooking here?